# com.google.inject.as: Guice provision errors when I instrument skype.apk

Tags: android, guice, skype

I planned to instrument skype.apk at android 4.2 emulator, using android support v4. I simply wrote

```
aut = new Intent();
aut.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
aut.setClassName(getTargetContext(),actName);
Activity act = startActivitySync(aut);
```

Start this app with "am instrument" and skype is indeed started. But it just quits with one glance. And the exception is as following:

```
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153): FATAL EXCEPTION: Thread-87
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153): com.google.inject.as: Guice provision errors:
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153): 
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153): 1) Error injecting constructor, java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/skype/android/util/cache/CompositeBitmapCache$1
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   at com.skype.android.util.ImageCache.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.util.ImageCache
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):     for parameter 1 at com.skype.android.res.CountryFlags.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.res.CountryFlags
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):     for parameter 1 at com.skype.android.res.ChatText.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.res.ChatText
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):     for parameter 1 at com.skype.android.util.cache.ContactMoodCache.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.util.cache.ContactMoodCache
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):     for parameter 4 at com.skype.android.util.ContactUtil.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.util.ContactUtil
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):     for field at com.skype.android.app.signin.AccountEvents.contactUtil(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.app.signin.AccountEvents
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   at com.skype.android.app.signin.AccountEvents.<init>(Unknown Source)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.app.signin.AccountEvents
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.inject.ComponentBootstrapProvider
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):   while locating com.skype.android.app.BackgroundComponentBootstrap
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/skype/android/util/cache/CompositeBitmapCache$1
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.skype.android.util.cache.CompositeBitmapCache.<init>(CompositeBitmapCache.java:75)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.skype.android.util.ImageCache.<init>(ImageCache.java:58)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.constructNative(Native Method)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:417)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.p$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:81)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.l.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.k$a.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ac.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.av$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ae.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.l.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.k$a.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.l.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.k$a.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ac.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.av$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ae.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.l.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.k$a.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ac.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.av$1$1.get(Scopes.java:54)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ae.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:48)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.inject(SingleParameterInjector.java:42)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.az.getAll(SingleParameterInjector.java:66)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.l.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:84)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.k$a.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:111)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:45)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ac.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:811)
E/AndroidRuntime( 1153):    at com.google.inject.ar.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.ja
W/ActivityManager(  286): Error in app com.skype.raider running instrumentation ComponentInfo{edu.umd.cs.guitar/edu.umd.cs.guitar.AUTInstrument}:
W/ActivityManager(  286):   com.google.inject.as
W/ActivityManager(  286):   com.google.inject.as: Guice provision errors:
W/ActivityManager(  286):
```

I don't know what is com.google.inject.as, neither google does. I am stuck at this and sucks.

Comment: Looks like ProGuard renamed the class, it was probably `CreationException` originally.

Comment: It is caused by third-party libs exported twice. According to http://juristr.com/blog/2010/06/android-instrumentation-test/